# Why isn't my data updating on db.SaveChanges()?

Tags: c#, data-binding, entity-framework-5

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BookExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly BooksContext db = new BooksContext();

        public Form1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.LoadBooks();
        }

        private void LoadBooks()
        {
            var books = from book in this.db.Books
                        orderby book.Author.Name
                        select new BookProjection { Title = book.Title, AuthorName = book.Author.Name, Price = book.Price };

            var booksList = new BindingList<BookProjection>(books.ToList());
            bindingSource1.DataSource = booksList;
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.db.SaveChanges();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.LoadBooks();
        }
    }

    public class BookProjection
    {
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is what the form looks like:

[image]

Here is what the model looks like:

[image]

Here are my table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Books] (
[BookId]   INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title]    VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
[AuthorId] INT             NOT NULL,
[Price]    DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookId] ASC)
);   

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Authors] (
[AuthorId] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]     VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AuthorId] ASC)
);
```

The program displays the data fine.  I can edit the data displayed. For instance, Frank Herbert's name is misspelled as "Frack".  When I correct the spelling and hit the update button, `db.SaveChanges()` is invoked (I watched in debug to be sure) but the database is never being updated.  I'm assuming I do not have my databinding in the program set up correctly.  Can someone offer me some advice on what to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this line

> ```
>         var books = from book in this.db.Books
>                     orderby book.Author.Name
>                     select new BookProjection { Title = book.Title, AuthorName = book.Author.Name, Price = book.Price };
> ```

...specifically `select new BookProjection` - when you create a new instance for each `Book` object, you've lost the reference back to the `db.Books` `DbSet`.

Either bind to the `Books` DbSet in your binding list (you can still control which columns are shown in the data grid's settings), or you'll have to stash a copy of the `Books` collection on your `Form1` class and update it manually with your `List<BookProjection>` changes from `BindingList`.